# Multiply elemnt width by data-role value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the data-role value from an object and multiply that objects width and height with that value.

Here is a fiddle of what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/kq7mA/

Please help if you can :)

```
var cssStyle = {
'background-color' : '#ddd',
'font-weight' : 'bold',
'width' : ('100px' * data-role),
'height' : ('150px' * data-role),
'color' : 'white'
}
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('li').css(cssStyle);
 });​
```

Comment: It's not possible to do in a way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kq7mA/2/

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var dataRole = $(this).data('role');
    $(this).css({
        'background-color' : '#ddd',
        'font-weight' : 'bold',
        'width' : (100 * dataRole) + 'px',
        'height' : (150 * dataRole) + 'px',
        'color' : 'white'
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cssStyle
    $('li').each(function(){
       cssStyle = {
         'background-color' : '#ddd',
         'font-weight' : 'bold',
         'width' : ('100' *     $(this).attr("data-role")),
         'height' : ('150' * $(this).attr("data-role")),
         'color' : 'white'
       }
       $(this).css(cssStyle);
    });                 
 });
```

We have multiple li with different data-role values. So have different width and height for each li we need to loop through each li. Also we cannot access data-role attribute directly in jQuery. Above code will fix your problem.

Check working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/kq7mA/6/

Comment: "since we are trying multiply string by integer." --- and in your code aren't you multiplying string by "integer"?

Comment: @zerkms in javascript '100' will automatically converted into number when we try to do any mathematical operation except addition, since '100' is valid number. But not the same case with '100px' since it is not valid number.

Comment: I know that, but `'100'` is still a string, while `100` isn't. In your code you're multiplying a string that is converted implicitly to an integer. And personally I don't see any reason to use string over a real integer in this case. Do you have any?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious things first: 
`data-role` is not defined and you cannot multiple such a string with a number (assuming `data-role` would contain a number).

Since you want to get the `data-role` from each element, you have to compute `width` and `height` by iterating over the elements:

```
var cssStyle = {
    'background-color': '#ddd',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
    'color': 'white'
};



$('li')
  .css(cssStyle)
  .css('width', function() {
      return 100 * $(this).data('role');
  })
  .css('height', function() {
      return 150 * $(this).data('role');
  });
```